# Silverlight serialization of a .NET Web service causes XML error

Tags: silverlight, web-services, serialization, wcf-binding

I've got this class being provided by a web service that is then being consumed by a Silverlight app (I don't know if that's relevant or not)

```
[Serializable]
public class Entry
{
    private string _title;

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get { return _title; } set { _title = value; } }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public List<Media> Media { get; set; }
}
```

The `_title` variable I added to demonstrate what's going wrong.  When I reference the web service in my silverlight app, it generates the folowing xsd:

```
  <xs:complexType name="Entry">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="_title" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Comments_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfComment" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Id_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Likes_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfLike" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Link_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Media_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfMedia" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Published_x003E_k__BackingField" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Service_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="tns:Service" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_Updated_x003E_k__BackingField" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element name="_x003C_User_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="tns:User" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Note only the title property is simply named, the others are named `<Link>_BackingField` which completely dies when you try and load the element because you can't have < or > in the name of a property.

Why is it serializing the backing fields and not the public properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx), when you use the `DataContractSerializer` (the default serializer for WCF) in combination with the `Serializable` attribute, the behavior is that all fields, public and private, are serialized. Because the backing fields are auto-generated in your case, the compiler comes up with funny names that have no chance of conflicting with any field names you might create (C# may not accept "<" or ">" in identifiers, but the CLR is not so picky).

Probably the easiest way to rectify this situation is to add `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes to the `Entry` class as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use automatic properties.
Instead of writing:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

write:

```
string id;
public string Id { get { return id;} set {id = value;} }
```

In case of Automatic Properties only backing field gets serialized and that's why you get strange names.